# Check if any names are present in two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two lists on names, first list of names just under 140k (Column A), second under just over 7k (Column B).

I want to see if there any matches from column A & B.

My Excel skills are basic at best. Any way I can do this?

Comment: Do you want a simple **Yes/No** or do you want a list of the matches??

Comment: Simple Yes/No would work

Comment: Then see my response....................

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a list you could try an array formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(List2,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,List2)+(COUNTIF(List1,List2)<>1), 0)),"")`
assuming your data is in A and B columns, I named a range in Col A `List1` and Col B `List2`
That formula would go in D2, hold CTRL-SHIFT hit enter, then copy to additional rows.
[image]

Comment: ...................Nice formula!

Comment: It has a slight problem, if there are dupes in column A it removes them from the list in D. Column D provides a unique list.
To fix, one changes the `<>1` to `<1`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function AnyMatches(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
   Dim v1 As String, v2 As String, r As Range, rr As Range
   AnyMatches = "No"
   For Each r In r1
      v = r.Value
      For Each rr In r2
         If v = rr.Value Then
            AnyMatches = "Yes"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Next rr
   Next r
End Function
```

[image]

The *UDF()* returns *Yes* because *Darth Vader* is present in both lists.